# OData exception The complex type 'WebTools.Order' refers to the entity type 'WebTools.Customer' through the property 'Customer'

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm getting started with OData and Entity Framework.

I created a Controller that exposes Customer.  In the model (edmx) there's only one Entity (Customer) and everything works fine (data is being rendered).

Now, when I add a second entity (Order) (Update model from database, select Order), the 1 to many (1 Customer to Many Order) gets setup automatically.

I do nothing else and when I compile/run the controller, I get this error:

```
Line 23:         builder.EntitySet(Of Customer)("Customers")
Line 24:         Return builder.GetEdmModel()  --> Exception Here
Line 25: 
Line 26:     End Function
```

The complex type 'WebTools.Order' refers to the entity type 'WebTools.Customer' through the property 'Customer'.

If I remove the Order Entity, it works.

I'm not sure if the problem is with the "configuration" of the OData/WebAPI part of the equation or the "Entity Framework".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I assume the model builder is not able to figure out the key property for the entity type Order. You can help out the model builder through a couple of ways,

1. `builder.EntitySet<Order>("orders");`. This adds a new entityset 'orders' and also has the effect of marking the type 'Order' as an entity type. You also have to specify the key property of 'Order'.
2. Mark the key property(or properties) on the type 'Order' with the `[Key]` attribute.
3. If you hate attributes and prefer doing it in code, you can do, `builder.EntitySet<Order>("orders").EntityType.HasKey(o => order.KeyProperty);`

Comment: If I have the Customer entity and another non-related-to-Customer entity (City or whatever), it works...  As soon as I include any "related to customer" entity (from the Update Model from Database), it fails.  My understanding with EF is that updates to the model using "Update Model from Database" will take care of handling the navigation/relationship between entities (right?).

Comment: Unfortunately, at this time the EDM model used by EF is different from the EDM model used by Web API OData. People generally don't prefer to expose their database model directly and instead use DTO's to keep them separate. We are working on improving the experience of model building for scenarios where you just want to expose your database model through your service. Until then you have to build the model yourself. Also, is it possible to share your Customer and Order classes? Just wanted to see why the ODataModelBuilder was not able to infer it properly.

Comment: Excellent, thank you.  I totally agree with your comment about exposing the db model directly, I was simply showing off OData to my team.  Thanks

Comment: RaghuRam, I'm updating my server from WCF DataServices with OData V1 (!) to WebApi2.1 and I've run into this exact issue. My problem is that my database is highly interrelated with 50 tables of 'live' data and another 100 tables of 'reference' and change tracking data. Pretty much every table is linked. At this stage I've partitioned the data using different EDMs. In my circumstance I'd LOVE to just expose the DB ;). Would love to have a chat regarding this but can't work out PMing in SO at the moment for some unknown reason...

Comment: This is such a frustrating error, I'm so glad this post was first in the results! I've been working with OData for many versions now, you forget that this can happen. Happened in our office when someone regenerated a database first entity model, and didn't name their primary key field with a suffix 'id' - so the table get's published as a complex type - because conventions couldn't identify which column was the key.