# Implementing OData with WebApi and Mapped Models

Tags: c#, entity-framework, odata, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to implement OData in WebApi.  I am using the repository pattern and EF5 (in the backend) which is still consistent with all the examples I have found.  Here is where thing go wonky.  I am trying to hide the EF generated classes behind models that are being mapped using AutoMapper in the controller.  The examples I have seen seem to return whatever comes out of the repo

I don't want to apply the OData parameters (to the results that have been mapped) in the controller but in the repository to preserve the value from delayed execution.  I can pass the ODataCriteria into the repository, but when I try to Appy, I get an error because it seems the options/results are typed to the IQueryable< Model > from the presentation layer not IQueryable< EF_Class >.

I saw someone else eluded to this in another post, however, it was a minor part of the post and it didn't seem to help.

Has anyone else dealt with this?  I really don't want to expose the EF classes.  Oh, I am using DB first.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code that demonstrates your requirement.

To achieve the result you need to ensure that the query has been executed (using `ToList()`). The most efficient way to do this is to add paging (bonus) and return a `PageResult<>` object.

```
public PageResult<WebPoco> Get(ODataQueryOptions<WebPoco> queryOptions)
{
    var data2 = DatabaseData();

    //Create a set of ODataQueryOptions for the internal class
    ODataModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    modelBuilder.EntitySet<DatabasePoco>("DatabasePoco"); 
    var context = new ODataQueryContext(
         modelBuilder.GetEdmModel(), typeof(DatabasePoco));
    var newOptions = new ODataQueryOptions<DatabasePoco>(context, Request);

    var t = new ODataValidationSettings() { MaxTop = 25 };
    var s = new ODataQuerySettings() { PageSize = 25 };
    newOptions.Validate(t);
    IEnumerable<DatabasePoco> results =
        (IEnumerable<DatabasePoco>)newOptions.ApplyTo(data2, s);

    int skip = newOptions.Skip == null ? 0 : newOptions.Skip.Value;
    int take = newOptions.Top == null ? 25 : newOptions.Top.Value;

    List<DatabasePoco> internalResults = results.Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();

    // map from DatabasePoco to WebPoco here:
    List<WebPoco> webResults; 

    PageResult<WebPoco> page =
        new PageResult<WebPoco>(
            webResults, Request.GetNextPageLink(), Request.GetInlineCount());

    return page;
}
```

Here's the using statements

```
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.OData;
using System.Web.Http.OData.Builder;
using System.Web.Http.OData.Query;
```

test classes

```
public class WebPoco
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class DatabasePoco
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

and some data for testing

```
private IQueryable<DatabasePoco> DatabaseData()
{
    return (
        new DatabasePoco[] { 
            new DatabasePoco() { id = 1, name = "one", type = "a" },
            new DatabasePoco() { id = 2, name = "two", type = "b" },
            new DatabasePoco() { id = 3, name = "three", type = "c" },
            new DatabasePoco() { id = 4, name = "four", type = "d" },
            new DatabasePoco() { id = 5, name = "five", type = "e" },
            new DatabasePoco() { id = 6, name = "six", type = "f" },
            new DatabasePoco() { id = 7, name = "seven", type = "g" },
            new DatabasePoco() { id = 8, name = "eight", type = "h" },
            new DatabasePoco() { id = 9, name = "nine", type = "i" }
        })
        .AsQueryable();
}
```

Comment: I like this approach, unfortunately, I am working with a legacy db and get the following error...The complex type x refers to the entity type Y through the property Z.  I cant seem to find anything about this on Google, I can only assume it is indicating the potential of a circular ref or something...

Comment: @Lenny - The `ToList()` should remove the db from the equation. But with EF mappings who knows?! It could be any number of things to do with Proxies, lazy loading etc. Which line fails?

Comment: check that this looks helpful... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15438195/odata-exception-the-complex-type-webtools-order-refers-to-the-entity-type-web   Thanks

Comment: After a bit of work your first suggestion has solved my issue, thank you very much...

Answer (score 0):

If the Queryable you return is via a dbContext.dbSet.Select(x => new Model { Id = x.Id}) mechanism instead of AutoMapper. Then applying conditions on the Queryable can be translated and evaluated by the EF LINQ provider automatically. Otherwise, you're going to have to write a custom LINQ provider which changes the expressions from being expressions based off of Model properties to expressions off of EF_Class properties.

Comment: Hmm, not loving that.  If I use the EF class then I wont be able to hide the id property (along with other id's) in favor of a navigation property which is the uri of the resource.  The only way that may still be possible would be through some ugly partial class work or changes to the t4 template the generates the EF class.    Am I going about this wrong?  Should I really just share the EF classes?