# ASP.NET WebAPI OData and different underlying model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I am working on new set of APIs for our existing project, which has rather complex database model. Therefore I decided that the REST API model will be different from the database one.

I would like to use OData since it provides nice query support. However I got stuck when I tried to convert between my two model definitions.

Basicly I need to do something like this (MagicConvert methods are pieces I am missing):

```
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<WebApiData> Get(ODataQueryOptions<WebApiData> options)
{
   ODataQueryOptions<Data> convertedOptions = MagicConvert(options);

   var results = convertedOptions.ApplyTo(db.Data);

   return results.Select(res => MagicConvert2(res)).AsQueryable();
}
```

I am of course able to write conversion of Data to WebApiData and back.

So my questions are following:

Is something like this possible (and how to do it)?

If not, does it mean that OData are ment just for (more or less) direct database access (without differing models)?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16606896/1515209) may help